# How to add MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, interface-builder, uibarbuttonitem

Would anyone be able to show me how to add a `MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem` to my toolbar in Interface Builder?  I have a `UIBarButtonItem` on my `UIToolbar` whose class I have set to MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem, but this doesn't seem the right way to do it.

I have the following property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem *trackingButton;
```

And I can add the button in code by using:

```
trackingButton = [[MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem alloc] initWithMapView:mapView];
NSMutableArray *items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:toolbar.items];
[items insertObject:trackingButton atIndex:0];
[toolbar setItems:items];
```

But I'm just missing how to do it in IB.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately this doesn't seem possible in IB due to the designated initializer of `MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem`. You have to instantiate it and add it to the toolbar programmatically, as you are doing.

Answer (score 4):

You can just add a `UIBarButtonItem`, and then make it a `MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem` in the class field in the identity inspector/IB sidebar, and add the button as an IBOutlet and then for it to appear you have to set the `mapView` property programmatically. With swift this can be done nicely in `didSet`:

```
@IBOutlet weak var trackingButton: MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem! {
  didSet {
    trackingButton.mapView = self.mapView;
  }
}
```

Or you can subclass and make `mapView` an `IBOutlet` so you can connect it in IB:

```
class UserTrackingBarButtonItem : MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem {
  @IBOutlet override var mapView : MKMapView? {
    get {
      return super.mapView;
    }
    set {
      super.mapView = newValue;
    }
  }
}
```